# Shell Script to Unzip/Extract zip files based on content code

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, zip

I have multiple zip files for each day but the content of files differ based on the first code for each file. So, based on the code, I need to pick files for processing. If the code is 100 in the zip file, I need to process it for the dev server.

How can I select 100 code file from below 4 files and process only that without unzipping all the files and only process the zip file for the current date, not all the files?

```
abc-20192010_185324.zip
abc-20192010_143564.zip
abc-20192010_196786.zip
abc-20192010_164564.zip
```

The contents are like this:

```
abc-20192010_185324.zip
100_abc
100_def
100_xyz

abc-20192010_185324.zip
101_abc
101_def
101_xyz

abc-20192010_185324.zip
102_abc
102_def
102_xyz

abc-20192010_185324.zip
103_abc
103_def
103_xyz
```

Comment: You can run `unzip -l` to list the zip file content, then grep the output.

Comment: As long as nothing in the file name indicates the contents of the file, you can't avoid reading the file. And are there multiple selectable ZIP files with contents having the same "prefix" or is there always a single ZIP to unzip?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I understand your question.  Do multiple types of files exist in the same zip file?  Your example has the same filename for each code file number.

Something like this may help point you in the direction you are looking for though:

```
for FILE in $(find ./*.zip -type f -ctime 0); do unzip -f "$FILE" 100*; done
```

find will look for zip files in current directory created today,
unzip will attempt to extract files starting with 100 from zip files found (note: -f will overwrite existing files without prompt).

Comment: Not bad, but you will read all the ZIP files all the time, even if the contents were in the first.

Comment: Yea i dont want to read all the files in the path i only want to pick the current date file

Comment: i have same file name with different time stamp receiving every day and inside each file i have multiple files with codes. So development file starts with code as 100 and uat file starts with code as 101 and so on so if am running code on development server i should pick the file which has code as 100 inside. let me know if now you understand my question.

Comment: once i find the correct file i need to move other same file with diff timestamp to backup path and proceed with correct file